# Primefaces filter datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hello guys I have a problem with my datatable I want to filter it, but if i put something into the text field nothing is shown and also if i clear the input also nothing.
It is possible if i have more than one statment in a column?

So I use primefaces 3.5 and jsf 2.1

Here is the code  and if you need more code post an comment. thx

```
<p:dataTable id="inboxTable" var="task" value="#{taskboxBean.taskboxInboxList}" paginator="true"
            widgetVar="inboxTable" rows="10" selection="#{taskboxBean.selectedTaskbox}"
            selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{task.ID}" emptyMessage="" paginatorPosition="bottom"
            filteredValue="#{taskboxBean.inboxList}">

            <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":contentForm, :postForm:tabViewPosts:inboxTable"
                listener="#{taskboxBean.onTaskboxRowSelect}" />

            <f:facet name="header">  

                <p:outputPanel>
                    <h:outputText value="Suchen:" />
                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="inboxTable.filter()"
                        style="margin-left:5px;width:150px" />
                </p:outputPanel>
            </f:facet>

            <p:column headerText="Post">
                <h:outputText
                    value="#{task.FROM_USER.FIRST_NAME} #{task.FROM_USER.LAST_NAME} (#{task.FROM_USER.EMAIL})" />
                <div align="right">
                    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!task.IS_SEEN}" class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x" />
                    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{task.IS_SEEN}" class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-2x" />
                </div>
                <h:outputText value="#{task.TASKTYPE.NAME}" />
                <br />
                <h:outputText value="#{task.CREATE_TIMESTAMP}" />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not explicitely written in documentation, but as mentioned on [PrimeFaces forum](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=8507), you need to declare `filterBy` attribute on columns you want to make searchable via global filter.

It is also suggested here to add `filterStyle="display:none"` to columns if you don't want a filter to be visible on individual columns.

The example from documentation has `filterBy`:

```xml
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{carBean.cars}"
        filteredValue="#{carBean.filteredCars}" widgetVar="carsTable">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:outputPanel>
            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />
            <h:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="carsTable.filter()" />
        </p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>
        <p:column filterBy="#{car.model}" headerText="Model" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <h:outputText value="#{car.model}" />
        </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

however, as typical for PrimeFaces documentation, it's not written that it won't work without `filterBy`.

Answer (score 0):

You must add getter and setter of your `taskboxInboxList` in the `taskboxBean` class. But it filters just the first statement placed in the column.